# MVC4 Ajax wait before executing the next process

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, async-await

In my MVC project I generate an array of images and store the array as a session variable, I animate the images using slidebar and by detecting mouse movement while mouse button is down by calculating the distance between the first click and x position while the mouse is moving on a canvas.

In the controller I use:

```
public ActionResult Animate(int slice = 0, int udm = 0)
    {
        FileContentResult data;
        Image objImage = null;
        Bitmap im = null;
        try
        {
                im = MySession.Current.imageArray[slice];
                ....
               MySession.Current.image = im;
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index",new {.... });
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }
```

and

```
  public ActionResult ImageOut(int udm = 0)
        {
            FileContentResult data;
            Image objImage = null;
            Bitmap im = null;
            im = MySession.Current.image;
            ...
            objImage = im.Bitmap(outputSize, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, m);
            MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                objImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
            }
            objImage.Dispose();
            return data;
        }
```

From the view I use Ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: '/Home/Animate',
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  data: {
        slice: ((lastX - firstX) + nSlice),
        udm: ++udm
        },
  success: function(data) {
   if (data.udm) {
   nSlice = (data.slice);
    image.src = '/Home/ImageOut?' + $.param({
     udm: data.udm
     });
     }
       },
        error: function() {
          }
       });
```

I have two problems, first it takes time to update the view and skips a number of images, the second is it open many threads and if a number of users accessing the same page it slows down.  I thought of using async but I am still using c# 4 and this may requires lots of changes to my code.  I was reading about SignalR, my question is can this be done (providing I just update the user screen not all users) or is there a better solution.

The sequence of events I would like to achieve is:

1. Ajax send to the first action a request or generate the first image and wait
2. When the image is generated, Ajax receive success, then    display the image on the screen using the second action
3. Then the first action generate the second image

The challenge I see is the first image keep generating the images    without waiting, so my question is how I make the first action wait,    and how to send to it a message to generate the following image.

I just installed VS2012 c#5, is there any example that can help me!!  Would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: SignalR is a great solution for 1 to Many messages, subscribe/publish/broadcast in comparison to what it seems like you need with a 1-1 message. There should be no problem updating to .NET 4.5 to make use of async/await. Otherwise you could always use TPL (Task Paralell Library) with the Task.Factory.StartNew method from the .NET 4 framework.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately VS2010 does not support 4.5.

Comment: That's fine, have you tried TPL?

Comment: I am learning about it now, thanks

Comment: I found the learning curve is beond my technical expertise, I can do just simple tasks.  Thanks for the information about TPL.

Comment: If loading images one-by-one server-side is not a requirement, I'd rather send the entire array of images in one call and handle animation logic with client-side JS.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing my program to use TPL because of the learning curve; I just added async: false to my ajax; this helped to delay the refresh of the screen.  Not the best approach but helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Using TPL, you could try this (taking your code above), the same can be applied for the animate method:

```
        public ActionResult ImageOut(int udm = 0)
        {
           FileContentResult data = null;
           Image objImage = null;
           Task.Run(() =>
               {
                   Bitmap im = MySession.Current.dicomImage;
                   objImage = im.Bitmap(outputSize, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, m);
                   using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                   {
                       objImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                       data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
                   }
               });
           objImage.Dispose();
           return data;
        }
```

Task.Run is just shorthand for Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: Thank you ianaldo21, so adding Task.Run() to both actions will solve the issue!  Just to be sure of the sequance:
I send the command from the viewer using ajax to animate menthod, when it is done, it will send the image file to ImageOut method, the output image is displayed using ajax success, then the second image will be processed.

Comment: I got the following error:
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run'